# Two swagger endpoints for a single application

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I've two controllers with endpoints in my application.
Now I also use swagger and swaggerUI to display these endpoints for documentation.
Currently both controller's endpoints are in the single swagger endpoint.
I want to split these into two separate swagger endpoints. Is this possible?

My current setup is very basic:

```
        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            var swaggerEndpoint = $"/swagger/{application_name}/swagger.json";
            c.SwaggerEndpoint(swaggerEndpoint, "swagger");
        });
```

Comment: Not sure you can do this, also not sure why you would want to do this? Maybe you could do it by leveraging the versioning feature of Swashbuckle...

Comment: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#generate-multiple-swagger-documents